# Rspec wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following a tutorial on Rspec from pluralsight.com.  The tutorial gives the following code which works on the screencast:

```
module Wordpress
  module Comments
    class Client
      def intitialize(url)

      end
    end
  end
end

describe Wordpress::Comments::Client do
  it "stores a URL" do
    client = Wordpress::Comments::Client.new("http://mashable.com/comments/feed")
  end
end
```

but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: client = Wordpress::Comments::Client.new("http://mashable.com/comments/feed")
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo: `initialize`, not intitialize

Comment: spelling errors are the worst, and tricky to find. I feel your pain :)

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error:

```
module Wordpress
  module Comments
    class Client
      def initialize(url)
        ...         
      end
    end
  end
end
```